# Unable to pass Json between controllers using routeParams- AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use angular's $routeProvider and $routeParams to control routing in my application. Among all the routes I have the following routes defined-

```
$routeProvider  
    .when("/home",{
    templateUrl : "home.html",
    controller : "HomeController"
})
.when("studentDetails/:student",{
    templateUrl : "studentDetails.html",
    controller : "StudentController"
})
.otherwise({redirectTo:"/home"});
});
```

Inside my home controller I have a function that will navigate to the student controller on a click event as follows-

```
$location.path("/studentDetails/" + studentDetails);  // student details is a json.
```

I am accessing this variable in my StudentController as follows-

```
(function(){
    var StudentController = function($scope, $routeParams){
        $scope.details = $routeParams.student;
    };
    var app = angular.module("dummy");
    app.controller("StudentController",StudentController);
}());
```

The problem I am facing is that the code works if I pass a simple variable (a string as the studentDetails), but it fails for a json. Is this the expected behavior or am I doing something wrong ?
If it is not possible to pass a json using the $routeParams, what should be the ideal way of doing this ?

Comment: if you want to multiple variable to pass into route you need to add multiple routeparam as "studentDetails/:studentid/:studentname" and $location.path("/studentDetails/" + studentid+'/'+studentname);

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I know a couple of workarounds for the problem, like the one you have suggested but is it possible to pass a JSON object directly instead of passing individual paramteres ?

Answer (score 2):

Ideal way is to stringify the studentDetails. Just do as follow.
In student controller on a click event,

```
var str = JSON.stringify(studentDetails);
$location.path("/studentDetails/" + str );
```

and in StudentController

```
$scope.details = JSON.parse($routeParams.student);
```

Thats it!!

Answer (score 0):

try following

instead of pass json variable pass as multiple variable

```
$location.path("/studentDetails/" + studentId+'/'+studentName);
```

and in route

```
.when("studentDetails/:studentId/:studentName",{
    templateUrl : "studentDetails.html",
    controller : "StudentController"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass an object with `$location.path`, use the `$httpParamSerializer` service.

```
$location.path("/studentDetails/" + studentId +
               '?' + $httpParamSerializer(studentDetails)
);
```

The `$httpParamSerializer` service converts objects to a [URL search query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

The route parameters are a combination of `$location`'s `search()` and `path()`. The path parameters are extracted when the `$route` path is matched.

In case of parameter name collision, `path` params take precedence over `search` params.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
// var str = JSON.stringify(studentDetails);
// $location.path("/studentDetails/" + str ); 
// $scope.details = JSON.parse($routeParams.student);
```

uh, not correct!

```
            //.when('/hs/:id/:name', {
            //$location.path("/hs/1/thuc101")
```